# Rust equivalent of Java HashMap initialization

Tags: rust

I'm looking for Rust equivalent of Java's HashMap initialization.

Java:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("1", Arrays.asList("one"));
map.put("2", Arrays.asList("two", "three"));
map.put("3", Arrays.asList("four", "five", "six"));
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#examples

Comment: Why not just input `rust hashmap` in your favourite search engine, as you would do for any other programming language? Rust is very well documented; many links lead to the reference or to some programming guides.

Comment: There's several Rust types that would work here, such as `HashMap<String, Vec<String>>` or `HashMap<&'static str, Vec<&'static str>>` or `HashMap<&'static str, &'static [&'static str]>` ... and many more combinations. Unless we know what the map will be used for, it's hard to say which type makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your strings to be `String` type, meaning, runtime strings:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("1".to_string(), vec!["one".to_string()]);
    map.insert("2".to_string(), vec!["two".to_string(), "three".to_string()]);
    map.insert("3".to_string(), vec!["four".to_string(), "five".to_string(), "six".to_string()]);

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

```
{"1": ["one"], "3": ["four", "five", "six"], "2": ["two", "three"]}
```

Otherwise, if the strings are all static and known at compile time:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("1", vec!["one"]);
    map.insert("2", vec!["two", "three"]);
    map.insert("3", vec!["four", "five", "six"]);

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Third, if your arrays are also known at compile time:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<&str, &[&str]> = HashMap::new();
    map.insert("1", &["one"]);
    map.insert("2", &["two", "three"]);
    map.insert("3", &["four", "five", "six"]);

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

For more information read about the `'static` keyword (which is implicitly used at our `&` types), `slices` and `the difference between &str and String`.

---

### Improvements

While the aim of the examples was to be as close to your Java code as possible, you could also initialize the map in a much cleaner way with `HashMap::from`:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let map = HashMap::from([
        ("1", vec!["one"]),
        ("2", vec!["two", "three"]),
        ("3", vec!["four", "five", "six"]),
    ]);

    println!("{:?}", map);
}
```

Comment: "Dynamic variables" isn't really a term used in Rust. There's mutable variables and references with non-static lifetimes. Additionally you can make initialization much simpler by `.collect()`ing an array of `(key, value)` tuples.

Comment: @cdhowie better?

Comment: Neat @`HashMap::from`. But that does give a `HashMap<&str, Vec<&str>>`, right? If you want `String`s, I guess [you have](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f309d24e49c397054e5101d82a2a2916) to collect? (And if you want `&[&str]`, you need the `&…[..]` trick, or `as_slice`.)

Comment: @Caesar no, to get `String`s, you have to add `.to_string()` to the `str`s.

Comment: Ah, true. Verbose, though. (`.into()` is a bit shorter.)

Comment: @Caesar Sure. You'd of course then have to specify the type of `map` explicitely. Although I disagree with the general notion of "shorter is better". That mentality regularly causes me to experience a lot of pain when working with legacy C/C++ code.